# PL/SQL library to emulate mysql built-in functions

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I need to convert the queries of a MySql-only project to Oracle.
Is there a PL/SQL library that emulates the MySql built-in functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library like you're asking for, there are some tools that might help you though. I found [this site](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql-to-oracle) that tells you the equivalent functions and data types between the two DBMS, and it looks like they have a free [online tool](http://www.sqlines.com/online) you could run your project through which might be the best option if it's not too big.

Comment: If you are in any way affiliated with that company (that you link to) you should disclose that in your answer. Otherwise this smells like  advertising

Comment: I'm not, never even used the service to be honest. This question just got me looking into what tools are available and that site looked like the best option available (oh god, it sounds like marketing again). If there's something better or some reason to not use their service, I'd happily remove my suggestion.